# Set size does not reduce even if object is removed from it

Tags: java

Given a code snippet

```
package setexample;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Mapit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        Integer i1 = 45;
        Integer i2 = 46;
        set.add(i1);
        set.add(i1);
        set.add(i2);

        System.out.println(set.size());
        set.remove(i1);

        System.out.println(set.size());
        i2 =47;
        set.remove(i2);

        System.out.println(set.size());
    }
}
```

The o/p comes out to be `2 1 1` instead of what i expected `2 1 0`. What is the reason ?

Comment: You're trying to remove `47` from a set containing `46`. What did you expect would happen?

Comment: @Kayaman OP doubt i guess is not about the value, is about objects and it's references... if you don't put `i2` in a `Collection` you can change the value from `47` to  `46` and use it only referencing the name

Comment: @Jordi Castilla Yes , but the i figured out java is pass by value, hence reference variable(i2) is updated

Comment: @AbhishekSingh this is totally true when you don't have any other reference to the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference of object previously named `i2` in `Set set` is not the same of the object named `i2` after line: `i2 =47;`. JVM has created a new reference for the object inside the `Set`, so you can remove it, but referencing the object in the `Set`, you can't remove it referencing it's by its former name.